# Change chart value color depends on standards in Canvasjs

Tags: javascript, php, canvasjs

I would like to represent my charts with two color, based on the value of the y axis elements.
Can somebody guide me how should I do that?

I'm using bar and area charts. 
Thank you!!!

Comment: You could provide more information. For example: the current appearance of your chart or look what you want to get

Comment: You can use color property to show entire dataSeries or particular dataPoint with your desired color.